# How to create a Reset Factory Barcode image for a Bluetooth Scanner?

Tags: bluetooth, scanner, barcode

I have a Newland NLS-BS80 Bluetooth Barcode Scanner and it has a "Restore Factory Defaults" Barcode in its manual printed in paper.

This barcode instantly reset the device to its factory defaults, so I want to create a web link based image of it for use of my co-workers.

So I scanned this Barcode with a Barcode Scanner app in Android to find out what is behind it and I found that its actual value is $$%^1207 but I don't know why when I make a Code-128 barcode in a online tool that contains same $$%^1207 value it can't reset my device?

The device just treats it as an normal barcode not a special reset one.

So where I'm doing wrong?
Thanks.

[Original factory reset barcode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W7nuO.png)

[My barcode created based on original one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ja5Qc.png)

Comment: Why not use an actual hi-res picture scan of the barcode?

Comment: I know that I can do that but I'm just curious that what's difference between this two identical barcodes and how the device detect it that its not the original one?

Comment: Both not the same barcode type? (aka not both code-128).  Not being rendered with the correct font?  There are so many reasons they might be different.

Comment: No both are Code-128 and I don't think font is important because I tried many different barcode generators with different fonts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your barcodes are not the same.

Yours is simply `$$%^1207` while the original one is `<FNC3>$$%^1207`.

Encoding FNC3 is dependent on your encoding program.
Try perhaps to add `^3` to the beginning of the barcode data.

Comment: So how can I make a FCN3 barcode? I'm using https://lindell.me/JsBarcode/ library for javascript but it can't create a FCN3 code-128 barcode. What is a FCN3 barcode and if there's any chance that I can create this barcode at all?

Comment: Many thanks, I found it with your guide, the solution is here: https://github.com/lindell/JsBarcode/issues/162

Comment: I just needed to add \xC9 to the beginning of barcode data